# loop through two muti-dimensional array at same time using foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

i am trying to loop through two multi-dimensional array with a foreach loop

```
[array1] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 1,2,3 ) 
[1] => Array ( 4,5,6 ) 
[2] => Array ( 7,8,9 )
  )
[array2] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 1,2,3 ) 
[1] => Array ( 4,5,6 ) 
[2] => Array ( 7,8,9 ) ) 
  )
```

both has same keys,

i want to access 1st array of both arrays at same time,
i want to do something like this

```
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1 && $array2 as $key2=>$value2)
    echo $value1[1]."  ".$value2[2]
```

its not correct, but that's what i want to do !!

Comment: is both array index is same???

Comment: yes, key upto 1st level are same in both array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the keys are identical between the two arrays in both dimensions :

```
foreach (array_keys($array1) as $key1) {
    foreach (array_keys($array1[$key1]) as $key2) {
        echo $array1[$key1][$key2].' '.$array2[$key1][$key2];
    }
}
```

Worst case scenario, some keys in one dimension or the other are missing in one or both arrays and you have to merge them prior to reading (and ensure the existence of the key's value in each loop & array).

---

**UPDATE**: used the same solution twice for two-dimensional array structure.

Comment: but i want to extract array values

Comment: See my update, you just have to apply the same logic to the 2nd dimension as well as the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, because you have same keys

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value) {
    for($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
        echo $value[$i]."  ".$array2[$key][$i];
    }
}
```

Thanks Maks3w for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if you can do this, i would use a for loop instead:

```
for(i=0; i < count($array1); i++)
{
   for(j=0; j < count($array1[i]); j++)
   {
       echo $array1[i][j];
       echo $array2[i][j];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i thought that we cant loop through associative array in this way, so i never tried it. but now my confusion is solved.